# How to pass back argument from child component on React Native

Tags: react-native

I have three file ( The full project is https://github.com/EnginYilmaz/kpbduser)

- MapScreen.js

  - FetchData.js
  - ShowData.js

I want to print a Map on FetchData and on marker click want to pass which markerkey pressed to MapScreen.js and then Query the people on index key and show data with ShowData.js but I don't know how to pass data back from
FetchData.js to Parent (MapScreen.js). I illustrated my question on [image: this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use props to handle data passing in react native. A basic example is shown below

```
export default class ParentClass extends Component {
    callbackMethod = (value) => {
        console.log('Callback is called',value);
    };

    render() {
        return <ChildView callbackMethod={this.callbackMethod} />;
    }
}



export default class ChildView extends Component {

    onPress=()=>{
        this.props.callbackMethod("Hello");
    }
    render() {
        return <Button onPress={this.onPress} />;
    }
}
```